# Step-by-step guide for installing a `.cls` file on Windows 8 with TeXnicCenter

Tags: installing, miktex, windows, texniccenter

I'm trying to install a `.cls` file on a Windows 8 machine, using the editor TeXnicCenter and the distribution MikTex 2.9. I have been directed to other threads, but find them incomprehensible.

**This is not a duplicate. None of the threads I have found have answered my question.**

I installed the out-of-the-box version of TeXnicCenter from CTAN. I have downloaded the `exam.cls` class file which I would like to use. But I have no idea how to install it.

Every other thread I could find uses language I do not understand, e.g. local file trees, etc. Moreover, the instructions say "click start, ...". While Windows 8 does not have a start button.

I need a step-by-step guide on how to get this class file installed and working. I don't even know where the files are kept. I really am a newbie when it comes to doing anything other than typesetting. *Please be kind and patient. Karma will reward you!*

Comment: As an initial thing you don't need to _install_ the file at all, just put it in the same folder as your document.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You're a legend! How simple was that?! People were telling me that I need to install it, i.e. make a directory, put it in there then update some database via command prompt windows(?) I guess I could just paste it into every directory that I need it. Thanks David!

Comment: I don't really recommend that you paste every package to every directory, things soon get out of hand. I just mentioned this to show that "installing" is essentially trivial you can put the files anywhere so long as you tell tex where to put them. However the advantage of using a package manager like miktex or texlive is that it knows where it put things and so can handle updates etc. So it is better to use miktex as designed, but you can figure that out in your own time, if you just want to get your document finished, the current folder works. I can't help with miktex details, never used it.

Comment: Given that this is MikTeX, the *easiest* way is to use MikTeX's package manager; `exam.cls` is on [CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/exam).  Follow MikTeX's [own instructions](http://docs.miktex.org/manual/pkgmgt.html) for its package manager.

Comment: have you seen this one? [How can I manually install a package on MiKTeX (Windows)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2063) As @SeanAllred says, `exam.cls` can be found using `MikTeX's` package manager- there's no need to do anything 'fancy' in this case... btw- `TeXnicCenter` has nothing to do with the package management

Comment: Bouncing off of what @cmhughes pointed out, your choice of editor *rarely* has an impact on actually *compiling* your document.

Comment: In addition to the MikTeX package manager, there is an official directory where MikTeX stuffs that stuff. On Windows 7, it is C:\Users\\[your account name]\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex (I'm not sure if its the same on W8). Putting it there and telling MikTeX to refresh its filename database (FNDB) will get the file recognized.

Comment: As it reads, this is a duplicate: neither the OS nor the editor make any difference to how to do a local install.